# wordpress fails to load my hooks

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, plugins

hello i've been dealing with this all day and i just can't figure out what is causing this problem please help me.
I have called a php file using ajax through the wordpress editor with a button.
This code is in my tinymce button file calling the php function

```
(function() {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('ImageSlider', function( editor, url ) {
function customfunction() {
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var dir1 = "../wp-content/plugins/Midnight Image-Slider/MDslider.php";
    $.ajax({
        url: dir1,
        success: function(data) {
            $('.mce-window-body').append(data);
        }
    })
})
}
editor.addButton( 'ImageSlider', {
    title: 'My test button',
    image: url + '/lion.jpg',
    onclick: function(){
        editor.windowManager.open({
            title: 'Image slider',
            width:800,
            height:450,
            body:[
            printCarousel(),
                customfunction()                
            ],
            onSubmit: function(e) {
            }
        })
    }
});
});
})();
```

And when it calls the php file it gives me this error 
wordpress Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
unless i write the require wp-config.php part at the top of the php file then the error goes away but it is still not loading any wordpress hook.

```
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../../wp-config.php');
add_action('init','loadFile');
function loadFile(){
echo 'hello world';
}
```

hello world is being displayed only when it is not in a function but i need to be able to use the wp hooks i think that some files are not being loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Your Ajax implementation method is not as per WordPress standard. 
WordPress made Ajax implementation very Easy with `wp_ajax_` & `wp_ajax_no_prev_` actions

you can explore more on Ajax implementation in WordPress from

[Custom ajax requests in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591764/custom-ajax-requests-in-wordpress)

https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

Comment: but ajax is not being called through php but through this js file i will edit my code with the entire js code

Comment: so that when i click my button it calls this function which loads a php file but that file does't seem to be able to load wordpress hooks

Comment: Your entire code is wrong.
how you can access WordPress `init` action without wp-load
do exploration on wp-load. 

and don't create complexity by adding PHP code in WordPress.
already WordPress made everything very easy 
just do a search of WordPress codex.

Comment: It will solve your problem. Through this method you exploring in the Wrong way.